# How to create a task with start date and end date in tfs?

Tags: tfs

Is there a way to set a start date and deadline for a task in tfs?

And then in the board I want to see some colorful tasks.

For example I want to see the tasks that are out of date and have not been finished yet in red color and some others in green and so on...

Comment: see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34079914/925202

Comment: Read this: https://edanan.wordpress.com/2017/10/17/add-start-and-endfinish-date-in-tfs-tasks-and-synchronize-to-project-tasks/ , it may help you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm assuming you are using Agile TFS template but this should apply to Scrum too(I think).

Agile template has Features, User Stories and Tasks in order of hierarchy. You an read more about them at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997897.aspx .

User Stories and Tasks do not have start date & deadline date since they are tied to a sprint and sprint start & end date are the start and deadline date for them.

Feature has a "Target Date" field because it is not tied to a sprint but that't not what you are looking for I guess.

If you absolutely need those fields then you can add custom fields in TFS.

**Adding custom fields in TFS:** http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh409273.aspx

For better dashboards and reporting look at Urban Turtle and see if it meets your needs:
http://urbanturtle.com.